# How would I test an attribute-based validation model with MSpec?

Tags: mspec

I have a model with certain attributes that restrict the values that that model can take.  How do I test the model state of this model using MSpec?

Comment: Do you have ideas how you would test with NUnit? Some code would be very helpful.